# Wrong key being set with HashMap in Intellij Idea

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, hashmap

Here is my function:

```java
public String uploadImage(URL image,String message) throws Exception{
    HashMap<String,String> paramArgs=new HashMap<String,String>();
    paramArgs.put("fbImgPostURL","https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos");
    paramArgs.put("accessToken",accessGrant.getKey());
    paramArgs.put("imageURL",image.toString());
    paramArgs.put("message",message);
    return HttpPictureUpload.uploadImageViaHttpPost(paramArgs);
}
```

and while i debug it from intelliJ debugger, strangely in the line

```
paramArgs.put("accessToken",accessGrant.getKey());
```

Clearly the key is `accessToken`. But the debugger shows it as follows:
[image: ScreenShot]

`access_token`=`CAACKan8suD0BAKUZAyxLinmXw2PZAkmkhIhVZCojG1sE2QsW60CfQjZAJWyMbqc1Lxy1JmVmSyAU4eHOGSkHhqJSQE6tcORuXAkyFbok7WGyysgJYZC6QF6KZBPRwDwbPCE6JUJgKIGyXzZCfzVgnjHHuoZBLZBt2xXgZD`

So clearly the problem is that I am setting a different key name but in hash map, a different key name is being set which is actually passed to

```
HttpPictureUpload.uploadImageViaHttpPost(paramArgs);
```

Anyone here could guess that what is going on?

**Edit:**
Here is my `uploadImageViaHttpPost()` function:

```
public static String uploadImageViaHttpPost(HashMap<String,String> keyParams){

    String in="Image Uploaded Successfully!!";
    try {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        PostMethod method = new PostMethod(keyParams.get("fbImgPostURL"));

        //Add any parameter if u want to send it with Post req.
        method.addParameter("accessToken", keyParams.get("accessToken"));
        method.addParameter("url",keyParams.get("imageURL"));
        method.addParameter("message",keyParams.get("message"));

        int statusCode = client.executeMethod(method);

        if (statusCode != -1) {
            in = method.getResponseBodyAsString();
        }

        System.out.println(in);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return in;
}
```

Comment: This looks like Base64. Are you sure this is not what this method is supposed to return in the first place, rather than the key itself?

Comment: @fge I do not know about that.But the problem is that I am setting the key "accessToken" but what is being set is "access_token". So in HttpPictureUpload.uploadImageViaHttpPost(paramArgs); when I try to access the parameter "accessToken",I get a null.

Comment: @fge this is really weird. Have you tried changing the "accessToken" String to something else to see if it's specific to that String? Other point I have, though probably won't impact this question is change the HashMap on the left to the interface Map.

Comment: The only thing I see here is the call to `HttpPictureUpload.uploadImageViaHttpPost()` actually altering the map. Can you try and add the `accessToken` element _first_ and see what happens?

Comment: @Jim even more weird things happening!! When I am changing the key or the value in thesecond line paramArgs.put("accessToken",accessGrant.getKey()), neither the key,nor the value is changing.It remains the same as:"access_token=CAACKan8suD0BAKUZAyxLinmXw2PZAkmkhIhVZCojG1sE2QsW60CfQjZAJWyMbqc1Lxy1JmVmSyAU4eHOGSkHhqJSQE6tcORuXAkyFbok7WGyysgJYZC6QF6KZBPRwDwbPCE6JUJgKIGyXzZCfzVgnjHHuoZBLZBt2xXgZD"

Comment: @fge thanks for your reply. I have added the HttpPictureUpload.uploadImageViaHttpPost() function.Pls See edit.

Comment: @rahulserver if you change the line (and it's key and value) and your output is still the same, it seems that your classes don't get compiled. Maybe you have some compile errors in your project or the classes were not compiled for some other reason? Unfortunately, I am not familiar with intelliJ.

Comment: @rahulserver the only thing I can think of is maybe this is the debugger transforming the specific String to be useful for debugging webservices. I'd drop down to some crude log lines to be sure.

Comment: @w4rumy I feel that u r suggesting the right thing.So a clean up and rebuild is necessary.Let me try it out and see.

Comment: @rahulserver Since you never showed up to answer if this was the solution, I assume it indeed was the problem. So you should think about creating an answer to tell other readers that this was the problem.

Comment: @Tom its been too long since I touched this project. So I can't remember what I did to solve it. So requesting the moderators to do whatever is necessary with this question. Maybe close or delete it?

Comment: Well, I don't now either what to do here. But you could ask about on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) (but search for similar questions first :P).